# PhoneGap app stops when no Internet Connection is available only on Android

Tags: android, cordova

We've created an app on Phonegap 3.5 using

- The device plugin,
- The network status plugin
- The iOS-Sim plugin.

There is essentially an RSS reader that saves via WebSQL on local device.

The app works perfectly on both iOS and Android **emulators** and on **iOS devices.**
However it keeps crashing on Android devices when no Internet Connection is available.

The error message we get is this:

> Unfortunately [appname] has stopped.

We used aLogcat but it doesn't even recognize the app as a process.

How can we debug the device itself? On the emulator it seems to work just fine.

---

**UPDATE:** :

We clean installed Cordova 3.4, we've created a new project which empty except for the plugins:

- Device plugin
- Network Information plugin
- Splashscreen plugin

Running the app on an emulator still works just fine
Running the app on an Android device with Wi-fi connection is fine

but

Running the app on a device with no Internet connection pops up a whitescreen for a couple of seconds and then the error message:

> Unfortunately [appname] has stopped.

Comment: Exactly. I'm also facing this problem currently. I'm guessing connection plugin has a new bug.

Comment: same problem here... narrowed it down to the network information plugin... any updates?

Comment: Had similar problems. This solved my problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790729/ios8-phonegap-cordova-network-information-app-crashes/26792735#26792735

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **Offline** event :

This event fires when an application goes offline, and the device is not connected to the Internet.

```
document.addEventListener("offline", yourCallbackFunction, false);
```

The offline event fires when a previously connected device loses a network connection so that an application can no longer access the Internet. It relies on the same information as the Connection API, and fires when the value of connection.type becomes NONE.

Applications typically should use document.addEventListener to attach an event listener once the deviceready event fires.

Example :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
}

// Handle the offline event
//
function onOffline() {
}

</script>
```

Source Link : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline

Comment: When I added this to my app, shut down the app, turned off wi-fi in Settings, then started up the app again, I get the message "Unfortunately, [app name] has stopped." My function onOffline was simply an alert, but that did not fire; the app would not start up at all.

Comment: 1st line... FATAL EXCEPTION: main ...2nd line... java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } in org.apache.cordova.networkinformation.NetworkManager$1@41f41de0 ...3rd line... at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher#Args.run(LoadedApk.java:773 ...and more... Since the app shuts down during the splash screen, your code is probably not at issue after all.

Comment: @Steve : Have you installed "network-information" plugin through cli?

Comment: Yes. I tried about 6 different approaches that I discovered online.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm getting the error as well. Blows up whenever wifi is disabled.