# iOS8 phonegap cordova network-information app crashes

Tags: ios, cordova

I use

- Xcode 6.1
- iOS 8.1
- cordova 4.0.0 (iOS 3.6.3)
- org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.13

First, when I add the plugin it never adds the SystemConfiguration.framework. I need to add it manually to the Buiild Phase.

Once this is done, the app can build but the it crashes on any offline event.

"updateReachability" is executed and the [self sendPluginResult] call originates and EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception on the _callbackId variable.

I found many reports since cordova 3.1.0. Is this just not working anymore or did someone found a fix for this problem?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I found the problem. Once you have ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) disabled in your XCode Project (Project->Build Settings) the Network-Information Plugin seems to cause a crash. So I fixed it by setting the option back to YES (in both Target & Project).

But in my case I had some classes which causes the build to fail with ARC YES. Therefore I added a flag `-fno-objc-arc` for each those classes in Project->Build Phases->Compile Sources.